# Отредактировать текст

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Помогите отредактировать. Пожалуйста. Спасибо большое.

Что касается моей личной жизни, в официальном  браке никогда не состояла, хотя более двадцати лет состояла в гражданском браке. Когда сейчас решила в корне изменить свою жизнь, мой партнер к этому оказался не готов и мы расстались. В связи с физиологическими проблемами детей не имею. Отвечая на ваш вопрос, почему решила выбрать именно ваш институт, могу сказать следующее: просмотрев информацию различных учебных заведений, пришла в выводу,  что вам институт даст мне необходимые навыки и знания для реализации моей мечты по созданию Центра психологической помощи  в постстрессовой ситуациях.

Answer (score 1):

Отредактировать, чтобы просто исправить грамматические ошибки?

Что касается моей личной жизни, в официальном браке никогда не состояла, хотя более двадцати лет состояла в гражданском браке. Когда сейчас решила в корне изменить свою жизнь, мой партнер к этому оказался не готов и мы расстались. В связи с физиологическими проблемами детей не имею. Отвечая на ваш вопрос, почему решила выбрать именно ваш институт, могу сказать следующее: просмотрев информацию различных учебных заведений, пришла в выводу, что ваШ институт даст мне необходимые навыки и знания для реализации моей мечты по созданию Центра психологической помощи в постстрессовой ситуациИ.

Или поправить сам текст? Странный текст для официальной бумаги, что бы это ни было. В официальном тексте не должно быть эмоциональных излияний и объяснений сложившейся ситуации в личной жизни, это никого не касается. Нужно короче и суше: Не замужем, детей не имею. Ваш институт выбрала осознанно: мне необходимы  навыки и знания для реализации моей мечты по созданию Центра психологической помощи в постстрессовой ситуациИ.